# Django ValueError

Tags: python, django

When I do the exercises on the book named Practical Django Projects，I meet some problem.When I click the Url about detail with my article,It return a error.
urls.py

```
url(r'^weblog/$','django.views.generic.date_based.archive_index',entry_info_dict),
url(r'^weblog/(P<year>\d{4}/$)','django.views.generic.date_based.archive_year', entry_info_dict),
url(r'^weblog/(P<year>\d{4}/(P<month>\w{3})/$)','django.views.generic.date_based.archive_month', entry_info_dict),
url(r'^weblog/(P<year>\d{4}/(P<month>\w{3})/(P<day>\d{2})/$)','django.views.generic.date_based.archive_day', entry_info_dict),
url(r'^weblog/(?P<year>\d{4}/(?P<month>\w{3})/(P<day>\d{2})/(P<slug>[-\w]+)/$)',"blogCategory.views.entry_detail"),
```

views.py

```
def entry_detail(request, year, month, day, slug):
    date_stamp=time.strptime(year+month+day, "%Y%b%d")
    pub_date=datetime.date(*date_stamp[:3])
    entry=get_object_or_404(Entry,pub_date__year=pub_date.year,
        pub_date__month=pub_date.month,
        pub_date__day=pub_date.day,
        slug=slug)
    return render_to_response('Entry/entry_detail.html',{'entry': entry })
```

Error:

```
Traceback :
ValueError at /weblog/2012/dec/04/test22/

time data u'2012/dec/04/test22/dec04' does not match format '%Y%b%d'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    /weblog/2012/dec/04/test22/
Django Version:     1.4.1
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

time data u'2012/dec/04/test22/dec04' does not match format '%Y%b%d'

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py in _strptime, line 325
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrong data is being passed to `strptime` see here:

```
>>> time.strptime('2012dec04','%Y%b%d')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=4, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=339, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> time.strptime('2012/dec/04/test22/dec04','%Y%b%d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 454, in _strptime_time
    return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2012/dec/04/test22/dec04' does not match format '%Y%b%d'
>>>
```

And the reason is because your first group isn't closed:

```
# yours
url(r'^weblog/(?P<year>\d{4}/(?P<month>\w{3})/(P<day>\d{2})/(P<slug>[-\w]+)/$)',"blogCategory.views.entry_detail"),

# change to
url(r'^weblog/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(P<day>\d{2})/(P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',"blogCategory.views.entry_detail"),
```

You had the first group closing around the `$` instead of before the first `/`